# Unable to link C++ with C object

Tags: c++, c, g++

I had been trying to link a cpp script to a c file using g++ compiler. But I keep getting global var in .c file declared as double definations.

.cpp

```
extern "C" 
{
#include "cFile.h"
}
```

Below is my method of compiling the 2 files.

```
g++ -c -o cFile.o cFile.c
g++ -c -o cppFile.o cppFile.cpp
g++ -o ExeFile cFile.o cppFile.o
```

Below is my error message.

```
cFile.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `NoOfRecordsRead'
cppFile.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
cFile.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `globalCountryDataArray'
cppFile.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Below is my raw header file as requested.

```
#ifndef COUNTRY_DATA_H
#define COUNTRY_DATA_H

// ====================================================================

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// ====================================================================

#define TLD_LEN             2
#define COUNTRY_LEN         100
#define FIPS104_LEN         2
#define ISO2_LEN            2
#define ISO3_LEN            3
#define CAPITAL_LEN         100
#define REGION_LEN          100
#define CURRENCY_LEN        50
#define CURRENCY_CODE_LEN   3
#define No_Of_Rec_Fields        11
#define Max_Record_Size         250
#define Line_Char_Buffer_Size   400
#define LINE_DATA_DELIMITER     "," 
#define INPUT_FILE_NAME         "Countries.txt"

// ===================================================================
//const char*   LINE_DATA_DELIMITER     = ",";
//const char*   INPUT_FILE_NAME         = "Countries.txt";

typedef struct CountryRecord

{

    char TLD            [TLD_LEN+1];            // Top Level Domain code

    char Country        [COUNTRY_LEN+1];    

    char FIPS104        [FIPS104_LEN+1];        // Ctry code according to FIPS104 standard

    char ISO2           [ISO2_LEN+1];           // Ctry code according to ISO2    standard

    char ISO3           [ISO3_LEN+1];           // Ctry code according to ISO3    standard
    double ISONo;
    char Capital        [CAPITAL_LEN+1];    
    char Region         [REGION_LEN+1];         // E.g. Asia, Europe, etc.
    char Currency       [CURRENCY_LEN+1];       // Full name of currency
    char CurrencyCode   [CURRENCY_CODE_LEN+1];  // Currency abbreviation
    double Population;

}   CountryRecordType;

int NoOfRecordsRead;
CountryRecordType globalCountryDataArray [Max_Record_Size];


// ====================================================================

void readData ();
char* get_line (char *s, size_t n, FILE *f);
CountryRecordType createCountryRecord (char* aLine);
void displayRecordContent (CountryRecordType ctryRec);
void showAllRecords ();  
int findCountryRecord (const char* countryName);    
char* getCapital (const char* countryName); 
char* getCurrencyCode (const char* countryName);
// ====================================================================

#endif // COUNTRY_DATA_H
```

Comment: You might want to show the `cFile.h` header file. Most likely you *define* variables there instead of just *declaring* them.

Comment: What does cfile.h look like?

Comment: the header file is kinda long..

Comment: Then post only the places where you have the mentioned variables (`NoOfRecordsRead` and `DataArray`). And please, edit your question to include those lines, don't post them as comments.

Comment: posted my entire header as I am not familiar with C programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your *cFile.h* file, the line `int NoOfRecordsRead;` should be:

```
extern int NoOfRecordsRead; // declare that this variable is defined somewhere
```

Then, in your *cFile.c*, you should have

```
int NoOfRecordsRead; // define this variable in exactly one place
```

---

What is problem in your current code is, you *define* a global variable in a *.h* file. So it gets defined in every *.o* file, where that *.h* file is included in compilation. And linker does not like multiple definitions like that. Only define stuff in *.c* / *.cpp* files which get compiled only once, to one .o file.

Comment: Do I do the same thing for the array?

Comment: If it outputs *same* error, reason could be stale .o files. Try full rebuild. Also grep for the symbol which gives error and check it is not defined anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

1) I would put `extern "C" {...}` *INSIDE* your header, not outside.

2) The problem is, I would put `extern int NoOfRecordsRead;` in your header.

Then actually declare "NoOfRecordsRead" in one ... and only one ... C or C++ module.

3) Do the same for `ountryRecordType globalCountryDataArray[]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

By combined solutions provided by hyde and FroggyDay. I created a .h for my cpp file and then copied placed my

```
extern "C" 
{
    #include "CountryData.h"    
}
```

into the cppFile.h along with other codes from my .cpp file.

I then followed hyde's solution to place extern for global variables in my c header

```
extern int NoOfRecordsRead;
extern CountryRecordType globalCountryDataArray [Max_Record_Size];
```

Finally, declaring the varibles in my c file.

```
int NoOfRecordsRead;
CountryRecordType globalCountryDataArray [Max_Record_Size];
```

I then can compile my script successfully.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The way this site works, you should not add a “thanks, this works” answer, but use the green checkmark to select one answer as “this solved my problem.”